# Recording a track, not a polygon in QField

Tags: qgis, gps, qfield, tracking

I researched the QField documentation, google, etc. but could not help myself.

My goal is to record a GPS track using QField.  However, the tracking function only seems to work in polygon layers. The recorded "track" resulting from this is a weird polygon shape of the track, not just the track itself.

In the bee farming demo it is also only possible to get the track as a polygon (tracking only possible in layer "fields"). 
I am assuming that this is just a user-error from my side, but I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: According to the [Documentation](https://qfield.org/docs/user-guide/track_lines_polygons.html) GPS recording should work with both line and polygon layers. The bee farming demo only has polygon and points layers, so that cannot be used for testing GPS tracking of lines. Do you have a line layer in your project?

Comment: Several tests later it just worked - must have been my mistake, I do not know what I did differently this time.